# C# detect if line in file exists, before attempting to read substring

Tags: c#, substring, read-text

I want to read settings from a text file.

```
string MySettingsFile = "Settings.txt";
```

Normally, the file would have 4 lines.

```
SettingA:Alpha1
SettingB:Bravo2
SettingC:Charlie1
SettingD:Delta6
```

I want to get each line in it's own variable, like this :

```
string MyAlpa = "Alpha1";
string MyBravo = "Bravo2";
string MyCharlie = "Charlie1";
string MyDelta = "Delta6";
```

Normally, I would just read the lines in a loop, reading each line and setting the string as I go.
If, however, Line 4 is missing, and I am looking for the part of the line after the colon, I get an error if I check for it like this...

```
MyDelta = MyDeltaSubstring(MyDelta.LastIndexOf(':') + 1);
```

Is there a way to 'check for the existence of a specific line' before  I attempt to get the SubString (so it doesn't get an error), like in 
a function separate that has try, catch, finally with return either the string I want or the word "Missing", if that line is missing (and then stop since there are no more lines)?

```
function DoesLineExist(int X, string myFile)
{
    string MyString;

    try ()
    {
        // read line X from file myFile
        // get everything AFTER the ":" and put it in MyString
        // ??? //
    }
    catch (ArgumentException null)
    {
        MyString = "Missing";
    }
    catch (ArgumentException e)
    {
        MyString = "Missing";
    }

    finally
    {
        MyString = ? // whatever we got From Line X (after ":")
    }
    return MyString; // only if line is missing
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?
ReadAllLines or something maybe?

Comment: You said it, you can use `ReadAllLines` and then you can compare the length of the list to see if that's what you expect

Comment: If you however want to go line by line, check out MSDN Read Line https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: could u plz show your `MyDeltaSubstring` function?

Comment: I think he might mean `MyDelta.Substring(etc)`. OP can you please provide a [MCVE]? There's something fishy about your question. Also please include the exact error message you receive. As far as I can guess, your code should handle a missing line fine but will choke if the line is present and the value after the colon is not. Is that correct?

Comment: Mayhem, the example ershoaib gave worked. I am going to mark that one as the answer because it gave a good working example that answered my questions and allowed me to solve my problem.  John Wu, the reason I didn't show an example is because I didn't have one. (If I had a complete example of how to do it, I probably would not be asking). Perhaps I am misunderstanding your meaning, but I don't see whats 'fishy' about my question. The code I presented might handle the exceptions, 'if' it were complete, but I had no idea what to put in certain places (where the question marks are). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first verify that that line is exist or not and then again check that is line contains key/value pair of settings is exist and then project your key value pair into dictionary and then get each setting to your variable by its key name.

Here i create a console app for your demonstration purpose.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dictSettings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        string MyAlpa = "";
        string MyBravo = "";
        string MyCharlie = "";
        string MyDelta = "";

        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\ConsoleApp4\ConsoleApp4\Files\Sample.txt");
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 1)
        {
            var line = lines[i];
            //DoesLineExist(line);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.Contains(":"))
            {
                string settingKey = line.Split(':')[0];
                string settingValue = line.Split(':')[1];
                dictSettings.Add(settingKey, settingValue);
            }
        }


        MyAlpa = dictSettings.ContainsKey("SettingA") ? dictSettings["SettingA"] : "";
        MyBravo = dictSettings.ContainsKey("SettingB") ? dictSettings["SettingB"] : "";
        MyCharlie = dictSettings.ContainsKey("SettingC") ? dictSettings["SettingC"] : "";
        MyDelta = dictSettings.ContainsKey("SettingD") ? dictSettings["SettingD"] : "";

        Console.WriteLine(MyAlpa);
        Console.WriteLine(MyBravo);
        Console.WriteLine(MyCharlie);
        Console.WriteLine(MyDelta);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    //private static void DoesLineExist(string line)
    //{
    //    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) && line.Contains(":"))
    //    {
    //        string settingKey = line.Split(':')[0];
    //        string settingValue = line.Split(':')[1];
    //        dictSettings.Add(settingKey, settingValue);
    //    }
    //}
}
```

**Input:**

```
SettingA:Alpha1
SettingB:Bravo2
SettingC:Charlie1
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Input:**

```
SettingA:Alpha1
SettingC:Charlie1
SettingD:
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. The ReadAllLines, combined with the way it checks for each line to see if the pattern exists first (before trying to read the line) was the trick to it. Thank you!!

Comment: @CopalFreak, glad to hear that you have get rid from your problem, if possible then vote up also by clicking up arrow to answer :)

Comment: Thank you downvoters, could u plz explain why downvote?

Answer (score 0):

Here is few different way to build the dictionary or list object we will use later. The choice is simple are those key unique or do you have multiple value for some `SettingB`. If the relation is one-one a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) could be a solution. Giving you access to method like [`ContainsKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.containskey?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
var regexDictionary = Regex.Matches(    File.ReadAllText(path)
                                , "(?<key>.+):(?<value>.+)")
                      .OfType<Match>()
                      .Where(m => m.Success)
                      .ToDictionary(m => m.Groups["key"].Value.Trim(),
                                    m => m.Groups["value"].Value.Trim());

var ObjList = File.ReadAllLines(path)
                     .Select(line => line.Split(':'))
                     .Select(x => new MyObject { 
                        prop1 = x[0],
                        prop2 = x[1]
                        // etc 
                      })

var linQDictionary = File.ReadAllLines(path)
                         .Select(line => line.Split(':'))
                         .ToDictionary(
                             c => x[0],
                             c => x[1]
                         );
```

Does the key exist in the dictionary?

```
if (!dictionary .ContainsKey("SettingB"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("For key = \"SettingB\", value = {0}.", dictionary["SettingB"]);
}
```

In a list of object:

```
if (ObjList .Any(x=> x.prop1 == "SettingZ" ))
{
    // Select the object. 
}
```

Comment: I will probably look into this method in the future. For right now, the answer ershoaib provided suits my needs. Thanks!

Comment: @CopalFreak, Well you should LinQ is not hard. And The answer are the same  ultimately. In fact I find `File.ReadAllLines(path).Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) && x.Contains(":"))
                         .Select(line => line.Split(':'))
                         .ToDictionary(
                             c => x[0],
                             c => x[1]
                         );` More clear. It works as it read: Take all line, where condition, select a the value in a dictionary.